# SHA2_256 Hashbytes generating different value on SQL Server 2012 with different version

Tags: sql-server-2012, hashbytes

I am facing a weird problem, I have one source - SQL Server 2012 with version no. 10.5.1753.0 - where hashbyte `SHA2_256` is generating a null value.

On the other hand, I have another source - SQL Server 2012 with version no. 11.0.3000.0 - where hashbyte `SHA2_256` is generating some value.

I have to deal with this problem, where I can't put request to source owner to upgrade their version and still I need to pull records from this source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versionnumber **10.5.1753.0** belongs to SQL Server **2008 R2** and not 2012.

[SHA256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) is only supported in SQL Server 2012+.

(BTW **10.5.1753.0** is a pretty [old version](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ch/) back from 2010 and **11.0.3000.0** is from 2012. They really should be updated.)

Comment: Great thanks, in this case then, if upgrade is not an option, which is the best algorithm we can use to generate hashbyte value on SQL 2008 R2.?

Comment: It depends on what exaclty you're using the hashes for. I recommend to create a new question with the [neccessary information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so people can help you. No one's reading all comments. If your original question is answered you should accept one answer.